# JQuery - Multiple Timeouts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where JQuery fires error messages depending on the requirements of the different fields.  I want the messages to pop up next to each field as needed, and I want each to fade in, have a 3 second timeout, then fade out.

But Im wondering:  is there someway to have an object or an array store all the timeouts?  Basically, all the errors are currently running off the same reference to the timeout.  So if one input fires an error, and another one does 1-second after, then the second message goes away in TWO seconds (rather than 3), because it's all referring to one timeout variable, and the first firing setup the initial timer.

This is for an order form, so Product refers to the parent `Div 'product'` for the input on which the error is being triggered.

I have something like this:

```
function error_check_number(input)
{
    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
    var product = jQuery(input).closest('div.product');
    if (!intRegex.test(input.val()) && input.val() != '')
    {
        input.val('0');
        if (jQuery('div.error-message', product).length <= 0)
        {
            var error = jQuery("<div class='error-message'>Number Values Only</div>").hide();
            error.appendTo(jQuery(product)).slideDown("fast");
        }

        var thetime = setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery("div.error-message", product).slideUp("fast", function () {
                jQuery("div.error-message").remove();
        });
        }, 3000);       
    }
    else
    {
        clearTimeout(thetime);
        jQuery("div.error-message", product).slideUp("fast", function () {
            jQuery("div.error-message", product).remove();
        });
    }
}
```

I would like each call to the error message, to function independently from one another, as far as the timeouts are concerned.

Comment: Then what is input? I don't think the problem is the timeout, It seems like you are using the same div for all errors so when one error slides up you slide up the div for the other error aswell.

Comment: But Im using `jQuery("div.error-message", product)`.  So, there's only one type of error for each product.  And because of my selector,  it only refers to the one in THAT Product.    `Input` is the input on which this error got triggered from

Comment: How you are displaying your error messages ?

Comment: ha oh boy.  Ok my summary code obviously was incomplete.  Just added the full code

Comment: I just had some good success with doTimeout.  Is this reliable as far as browsers are concerned? http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this with doTimeout() and it seems to work well.  Any reason why I shouldn't use this?

benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin

```
function error_check_number(input)
{
    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
    var product = jQuery(input).closest('div.product');
    if (!intRegex.test(input.val()) && input.val() != '')
    {
        input.val('0');
        if (jQuery('div.error-message', product).length <= 0)
        {
            var error = jQuery("<div class='error-message'>Number Values Only</div>").hide();
            error.appendTo(jQuery(product)).slideDown("fast");
        }
        jQuery.doTimeout(jQuery(input).attr('name'), 3000, function(){
            jQuery("div.error-message", product).slideUp("fast", function () {
                jQuery("div.error-message", product).remove();
        });
        }, true);

    }
    else
    {
        jQuery.doTimeout(jQuery(input).attr('name'), function(){
            jQuery("div.error-message", product).slideUp("fast", function () {
                jQuery("div.error-message", product).remove();
        });
        }, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (!intRegex.test(input.val()) && input.val() != '')
{
    input.val('0');
    if (jQuery('div.error-message', product).length <= 0)
    {
        var error = jQuery("<div class='error-message'>Number Values Only</div>");
        error.appendTo(jQuery(product)).slideDown("fast", function(){
            var timeout=setTimeout(function(){ 
                error.slideUp("fast", function () {
                    error.remove();
                });
            }, 3000);
        });
    }
}
```

I think without a visual example I can't go further.

Comment: well this seems to be working ok, but one problem im having is that:  If the user enters and error, the message comes up, but i they change it and its still an error, Id like the timer to reset.  Right now, it just continues counting down

Comment: i get an error that `error.slideUp` is not a function.  I suppose slideUp needs to be applied directly to a selector

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine, untested but I think it will work

```
function error_check_number(input) {
    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
    var product = jQuery(input).closest('div.product');
    var error_div = product.find('div.error-message');

    function displayError(msg, field_name) {
       var error = $('<div class="error" id="error_for_'+field_name+'">'+msg+'</div>').hide();
       error.appendTo(error_div).slideDown("fast");

       error[0].timer = setTimeout(function(){
              error.slideUp("fast", function () {
                 error.remove();
              });
      }, 3000);       
    }

    if (!intRegex.test(input.val()) && input.val() != '') {
        input.val('0');
        displayError("Number Values Only");
    } else {
        err = error_div.find("#error_for_"+input.attr('name'));
        if (err[0]) {
           clearTimeout(err[0].timer)
           err.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes, div.error-message always exists. This acts as a container for all the error messages. It doesn't remove the container. If you don't like this behavior, you can simply append it to "div.product"

Comment: actually, see Sheikh Heera's answer. This is only useful for multiple fields and multiple error messages in a common error messages container. That's not what you were doing. So scratch this answer.